# Two confusions about torsion-free coherent sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, modules, sheaf-theory

(**EDIT:** Beware, my definition of torsion-free is incorrect below. The correct one is to say $\mathcal{F}$ is torsion-free if for all $x \in X$, and all $s \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}-\{0\}$, the multiplication by $s$ map $\mathcal{F}_{x} \to \mathcal{F}_{x}$ is injective.  This resolves the issue.)

Let $X$ be an integral Noetherian scheme, and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a coherent sheaf on $X$.  One can consider the morphism of $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-modules

$$\mathcal{O}_{X} \to \mathcal{H}om_{\mathcal{O}_{X}}(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{F})$$

mapping a function $f \in \mathcal{O}_{X}(U)$ to the multiplication by $f$ map $\mathcal{F}|_{U} \to \mathcal{F}|_{U}$.  The kernel is called the *annihilator ideal sheaf*, and the corresponding closed subscheme is $\text{Supp}(\mathcal{F})$.

I want to define $\mathcal{F}$ to be *torsion-free* when the annihilator ideal sheaf vanishes, and *torsion* otherwise.  I'm able to show that:

1. If $\mathcal{F}$ is torsion-free, then $\text{Supp}(\mathcal{F})=X$.
2. $\mathcal{F}$ is torsion-free if and only if $\mathcal{F}_{x}$ is a torsion-free $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$-module for all $x \in X$.
3. $\mathcal{F}$ is torsion-free if and only if it has no non-trivial torsion subsheaves.

Now, the converse of (1) is obviously false: if $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{L} \oplus \mathcal{O}_{p}$ is the direct sum of a line bundle and skyscraper sheaf, then $\text{Supp}(\mathcal{F})=X$, but $\mathcal{F}$ is not torsion-free.  However, since the annihilator ideal sheaf should be the ideal sheaf corresponding to X, it must be zero?  Contradicting that $\mathcal{F}$ isn't torsion-free?  Moreover, in this example above, it seems like the annihilator ideal sheaf should vanish at all stalks except $p \in X$.  Which cannot happen for an ideal sheaf.  Where am I going so badly wrong here?  Is it related to support vs. scheme-theoretic support?

My second confusion is with showing that my definition of torsion-free is equivalent to the rank $rk(\mathcal{F}) = dim_{\mathcal{O}_{X, \eta}}\mathcal{F}_{\eta}$ being larger than zero, where $\eta \in X$ is the generic point.  I think its clear that my definition implies this one.  But conversely, how can one show that $\mathcal{F}_{x}$ is torsion-free for all $x \in X$ just from this data at $\eta \in X$?  I know that all open sets of $X$ contain $\eta$; it must be using that somehow?

Comment: Your definition of torsion-free is not the standard definition. How did you prove 3 for example?

Comment: @Mohan I got that definition from the second paragraph on page 4 of (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/HuybrechtsLehn.pdf).  Since a map of sheaves is injective if and only if its injective at all stalks, isn't what I wrote equivalent to that document?  Immediately after, they mention that by the torsion filtration, it's equivalent that there are no torsion subsheaves.

Comment: For example, if $X$ is integral, $O_X\oplus O_x$, where $O_x$ is the skyscraper sheaf at $x\in X$  (as you said) is not torsion-free in the usual definition, but the annihilator sheaf is zero. The article you cite does not say what you say, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Mohan Isn't what they say at the top of page 4 equivalent to saying that $\mathcal{O}_{X, x} \to Hom(\mathcal{F}_{x}, \mathcal{F}_{x})$ is injective for all $x \in X$?

Comment: No, they say that multiplication by any non-zero $s$ from $ F_x\to F_x$ is injective. Is that the line you are referring to?

Comment: @Mohan You are right, of course.  I was being far too careless.  I think this resolves my contradiction, thanks!